# How to modify HTTP request before sending in JMeter through Beanshell pre processor?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have test case in my csv file. The request URL has a *custom* variable.

Sample URL : `.../abc/$id`

I need to replace this `id` by the `id` that we get in response from the previous request. I used json extractor to fetch  the `id` from the response. Now I need to update this `id` in the next test case request. Fetched the Request URL from jmeter context using below code:

```
String path = ctx.getCurrentSampler().toString(); 
path.replaceAll("$id", id);
```

I am not able to set this updated URL in jmeter context (`ctx`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to assign new path value to `path` variable
2. You need to set sampler path to the new value using [sampler.setPath() method](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#setPath-java.lang.String-)

So you need to amend your code like:

```
String path = ctx.getCurrentSampler().toString();
path = path.replaceAll("$id", id);
sampler.setPath(path);
```

Demo:

[image: JSR223 PreProcessor change path]

---

Also consider switching to [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](http://groovy-lang.org/) as Groovy performance is much higher, it better supports new Java features and provides some extra "syntax sugar" on top. See [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for details.

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid the pre / post processors if possible.
Your requirement is very simple and straight forward.

Directly use this in the path - assuming `id` is the name of variable which has the value.

`/abc/${id}`